# I'm trying to identify a short story title, maybe "Killbird"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence, crime

I read this in an anthology over 35 years ago.  The paperback was probably 10 to 15 years old.

Basic plot was a series of robot birds, AI that could learn, set free prevent murders.  They decided that more actions constituted murder far beyond what the designers intended.  Examples:  preventing surgery because the incision would harm the patient, not allowing a farmer to turn off his tractor.  Vaguely remember the robots giving electric shocks; in one instance, a person died from a weak heart, all because he was trying to swat a fly.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=short%20story%20%28killbird%20or%20%22kill%20bird%22%29&btnK=) wasn't much help

Comment: Thank you phantom42.  That is exactly the story I meant.

Comment: that is quite a phantom!

Answer (score 3):

["Watchbird"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46236) by Robert Sheckley. Project Gutenberg [etext](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29579). Here is a [scanned copy](http://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1953-02/Galaxy_1953_02#page/n75/mode/2up) of the original *Galaxy* publication with illustrations by Ed Emshwiller. That story has appeared in [these collections](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?46236); if the one you read it in was from about 50 years ago, it was probably one of [these](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?38467). More information [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49366/scifi-work-that-had-artificial-birds-turning-on-humans); this story has been identified before, but with different plot points in the question.

**Examples: preventing surgery because the incision would harm the patient,**

> The nurse handed the surgeon the sponge.
>
> "Scalpel."
>
> She placed it in his hand. He started to make the first incision. And then he was aware of a disturbance.
>
> "Who let that thing in?"
>
> "I don't know," the nurse said, her voice muffled by the mask.
>
> "Get it out of here."
>
> The nurse waved her arms at the bright winged thing, but it fluttered over her head.
>
> The surgeon proceeded with the incision—as long as he was able.
>
> The watchbird drove him away and stood guard.
>
> "Telephone the watchbird company!" the surgeon ordered. "Get them to turn the thing off."
>
> The watchbird was preventing violence to a living organism.
>
> The surgeon stood by helplessly while his patient died.

**not allowing a farmer to turn off his tractor.**

> Jackson yawned and pulled his car to a shoulder of the road. He didn't notice the glittering dot in the sky. There was no reason for him to. Jackson wasn't contemplating murder, by any human definition.
>
> This was a good spot for a nap, he decided. He had been driving for seven straight hours and his eyes were starting to fog. He reached out to turn off the ignition key—
>
> And was knocked back against the side of the car.
>
> "What in hell's wrong with you?" he asked indignantly. "All I want to do is—" He reached for the key again, and again he was smacked back.
>
> Jackson knew better than to try a third time. He had been listening to the radio and he knew what the watchbirds did to stubborn violators.
>
> "You mechanical jerk," he said to the waiting metal bird. "A car's not alive. I'm not trying to kill it."
>
> But the watchbird only knew that a certain operation resulted in stopping an organism. The car was certainly a functioning organism. Wasn't it of metal, as were the watchbirds? Didn't it run?

**Vaguely remember the robots giving electric shocks; in one instance, a person died from a weak heart, all because he was trying to swat a fly.**

> The fly buzzed around the room, lighting on a table top, pausing a moment, then darting to a window sill.
>
> The old man stalked it, a rolled newspaper in his hand.
>
> Murderer!
>
> The watchbirds swept down and saved the fly in the nick of time.
>
> The old man writhed on the floor a minute and then was silent. He had been given only a mild shock, but it had been enough for his fluttery, cranky heart.